# How to import .reg file via Inno Setup

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I have a registry file (.reg) and I need to execute it while installing in silent. I don't want to use `[Registry]` section to add every registry key.

The registry key is in path:

```
C:\MyInstaller\bathkey.reg
```

Is it possible to import the registry file without adding each item to the `[Registry]` section?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`reg import` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-import):

```
[File]
Source: "C:\MyInstaller\bathkey.reg"; DestDir: "{tmp}"

[Run]
Filename: "reg"; Parameters: "import ""{tmp}\bathkey.reg"""
```

Comment: Great, Thank you very much